# How to install GDAL 1.10 with OGR SQLite driver support on Ubuntu?

Tags: gdal, installation, ubuntu

How can I install GDAL 1.10 with OGR SQLite driver support, and JPEG and PNG drivers per http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mbtiles.html

Comment: What system are you using (Windows, OS X, *nix)?

Comment: For the ubuntu OS

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are installing GDAL from source and you are getting them through SVN. GDAL can be compiled with SQLite, JPEG and PNG drivers by specifying the necessary flags during configuration.

Once the SVN download/update of sources is completed, move to the directory and issue this command:

```
./configure
```

This will result in a output similar to this after a while:

```
  Installation directory:    /usr/local
  C compiler:                gcc -g -O2 -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME
  ...............
  .................
  12 bit JPEG:               no
  12 bit JPEG-in-TIFF:       no
  ..................
  ...................
  Rasdaman support:          no
  DODS support:              no
  SQLite support:            yes
  PCRE support:              yes

  enable OGR building:       yes
  enable pthread support:    yes
  enable POSIX iconv support:yes
  hide internal symbols:     no
```

In my case SQLite support had a 'yes' flag as above but JPEG had 'no'.

Once you understand the above result, you can go with custom configuration like.

```
./configure --with-png=internal --with-jpeg=internal
```

After configuration you will have to run

```
make -j2  &&  sudo make install  &&  sudo ldconfig
```

for installation.

Just today I published a blog post which discusses installation of GDAL 1.10 for GeoPDF to GeoTIFF conversion. You can get information on installing GDAL 1.10 when you have other GDAL versions installed on your PC from that [post](http://www.staygeo.com/2013/03/convert-geopdf-maps-to-geotiff-with-gdal.html).